# HTML Tag are not rendered on Microsoft Team Bot which is deployed via Azure Service

Tags: html, azure, azure-active-directory, botframework, bots

I have developed **Web app bot in Azure servic**e and **deployed on MS Team** through channels.

On clicking on Microsoft team channel it will redirect to team platform.
On Microsoft Team UI Bot, in response section:
while response coming from web app bot to team platform, it contains html tags for e.g.   etc.

**some html tags are not rendered correctly like &nbsp, button, iframe etc.**

and these HTML tags are not being rendered on Microsoft Team platform UI.

anyone knows solution for this problem?

Comment: Bot framework does not officially support HTML in any channel.  Some HTML will work on some channels, but as I said it is not officially supported.  I would not recommend coding your bot to rely on HTML.

Comment: I removed my reply, but for the "platform-agnostic" argument of the bot framework, given the number of issues that are platform specific, I can't really agree.

Comment: @NicolasR That's not what I meant by it being platform-agnostic. By saying it is platform-agnostic, I mean the limitations of HTML in messages. They are not supported by the bot framework regardless of *where* you use the bot. If the answer is "see my answer to another question about it not being supported in the bot framework when used in a different application", then this is a duplicate. In the words of the system, "this question already has an answer [somewhere]"

Comment: To add some content to the other reply: a blog post from the bot framework team explaining why it is not supported https://blog.botframework.com/2017/09/07/html-not-supported-web-chat/

Comment: Lets combine our comment into an answer for people asking this question in the future, thanks for the link Nicolas, forgot about that :)

Answer (score 0):

Bot framework does not officially support HTML in any channel. Some HTML will work on some channels, but as I said it is not officially supported. I would not recommend coding your bot to rely on HTML.  You can find details about the use of HTML and why it is not supported in [this blog](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/09/07/html-not-supported-web-chat/).  The blog specifically covers webchat, but the unsupported HTML applies to all channels bot framework supports.